# Security exception with using parse.com api

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am relatively new to using parse.com api, I followed the instructions give on their site. I then wrote the following code in my launcher activity's onCreate() method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ParseObject.registerSubclass(VendorLocationModel.class);
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this); // enable parse local data store
    Parse.initialize(this, "Api_key", "client_key"); // initialize the parse with API key
}
```

I am getting a security exception as follows:

```
142-3156/prototype.quest.cashquest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Parse.initialize Disk Check & Starting Command Cache
java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10076 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1431)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1385)
        at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getActiveNetworkInfo(IConnectivityManager.java:720)
        at android.net.ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.java:522)
        at com.parse.ConnectivityNotifier.isConnected(ConnectivityNotifier.java:89)
        at com.parse.ParsePinningEventuallyQueue.<init>(ParsePinningEventuallyQueue.java:66)
        at com.parse.Parse.getEventuallyQueue(Parse.java:421)
        at com.parse.Parse$1.run(Parse.java:147)
```

I have actually included the following in manifest file (which is mandatory)

```
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

if I comment the lines which are related to parse.com API in onCreate().. then the app runs fine but if I include it app crashes with the above exception, Please let me know if any of you can figure out what might be wrong or what I might be missing..

**EDIT** Here is the whole manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:name=".PrototypeApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: When you install this without adb i.e by copying the APK onto your phone to install it, what permissions does it ask for? Check to make sure that it is actually asking for the `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission. If not.. that's where I'd be looking! :)

Comment: yup I got your point ,,! but I already have the using-permission thing mentioned in manifest ,,, I tried installing the app-debug.apk by copying it on phone, surprisingly it just got installed without anything being asked.... at first It said "Do you want to install this app , this app does not require any special access" thats all installed without interruption !

Comment: Could you post the rest of your manifest? It looks like those permissions aren't being picked up for some reason.

Comment: Try moving your'<use-permission> tags above the <application> tag